# PhpStorm и файлы по ссылке

Tags: php, phpstorm

В новых версиях PhpStorm перестал видеть при синхронизации локальные файлы которые добавлены в проект ссылкой, а потому не учитывает их при сравнении с хостом. Кто-то сталкивался с этим? И если решили то подскажите как.

Answer (score 0):

В Phpstorm зайти в `deployment->options`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поставить галку для notify `about remote changes`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же необходимо в deployment->configuration во вкладке в Сonnection 
настроить  path roots

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению не помогло. При синхронизации файлы по ссылке так и не видит и пытается слить их с хоста. Пока спасаюсь полной заливкой на хост после внесённых изменений.